# unmerge tables in fusiontables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've a merged table in fusiontables and I want to unmerge it (i.e., detach a table from it). Is it possible? If yes, how?

I would like not to start everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unmerge a table, but you should still have the original tables you merged with, right?